# Override default crypto system used in ATS with custom crypto system

Tags: ios, security, app-transport-security

1. Is there any way to override the default transport layer security in iOS app ?
   ie. to use a custom openssl library for ATS.
   https://developer.apple.com/reference/security/secure_transport
2. Is there any way to override default crypto system in ATS using a customised version?
   If so how to do that? Any documentation

Thanks,
Abhilash.

Answer (score 1):

ATS only applies to NSURLSession, the now-deprecated NSURLConnection, and APIs layered on top of them.  It does not apply to apps that use lower-level APIs (like BSD Sockets), including those that implement TLS on top of those lower-level APIs.  If you are using a 3rd party library like openssl, the ATS requirements will not be enforced.

ATS is not providing any encryption itself.  ATS is a set of mandatory minimums on the encryption / handshake of the connections made with NSURLSession.  So requiring a minimum TLS of 1.2, strong keys, forward secrecy, etc.  I think you may not have a clear understanding of app transport security.

If you want to write your own SSL implementation, or use a 3rd party library to do so, ATS would not be in play at all, unless you try to utilize NSURLSession in your implementation.